# How to store Non-serializable object to sqlite in android ? or also you can suggest any another way to store nonserializable arralylist objest

Tags: java, android, sqlite, serialization

I was to store nonserializable object to sqlite in android. but its give me error of object is not Serializable. i just want to know, is that possible or any another way to store this objects ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write your own serialization?

Comment: yes, but i already try this. my object is ArrayList<BlutoothGattService>.

Comment: What's a BlutoothGattService?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattService.html

Comment: Look at this [site](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2097430/java-se/serializing-java-objects-with-non-serializable-attributes.html)

Comment: see my last answer. i have already done which you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through below,

```
class MyArrayList<BlutoothGattService> extends ArrayList<BlutoothGattService> implements Serializable{

}
```

Then use this class instead of ArrayList and you can easily Serialize object of this class.

I think it will help.

Comment: Ohk.. if you need any kind of help regarding in this implementation than just put a comment here.